# Java with a compiled C dll issue

Tags: java, eclipse, dll, crt

I have a java project in eclipse that contains a DLL that was compiled on a seperate machine. I am on Windows 7, 64 bit and eclipse is for 64 bit also.

I am unable to compile the project, with error: "The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect..."

Event viewer shows: "Dependent Assembly Microsoft.VC90.DebugCRT,processorArchitecture="x86",publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b",type="win32",version="9.0.21022.8" could not be found. Please use sxstrace.exe for detailed diagnosis."

I had visual studio 2008 and 2010, both x64, installed on my machine.

I uninstalled Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 x64, and downloaded Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable x86 9.0.30729.4148, which I found on that site: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26368, but it does not help.

Does the error still occurs due to the difference in versions, i.e 9.0.21022.8 instead of 9.0.30729.4148?
How do I solve my problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it seems likely that the problem is mixed versions of the C runtime library, caused by your re-installation of visual studio.

This Microsoft support page may help: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2525435